# Loading huge binary file partially into Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, binaryfiles, mat-file

I have a huge binary file with double precision numbers and I would like to load parts of it into Matlab. Is there a way to do this?

One way would be if I could convert it to a .mat file (without loading it in Matlab first), but I haven't been able to figure out how (or if it's actually possible).

Any ideas?

PS: I was thinking of using c++ to do the conversion but it turns out this is really problematic because I'm using a linux version of c++ (through cygwin) and a windows version of Matlab.

Comment: From the documentation: *fopen(filename) opens the file, filename, for binary read access* Away you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what parts of the file you want to load, you can use [`fseek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) followed by `fread` (both preceded by `fopen`, of course).

For example, jump a few thousand bytes into a file and read a certain number of bytes, as doubles:

```
fid = fopen('binary.dat','r');
fseek(fid, 3000, 'bof');
A = fread(fid, N, 'double');
fclose(A); % don't forget to close the file
```

See the section of documentation called [Reading Portions of a File](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/importing-binary-data-with-low-level-i-o.html#br4luzp) for more information.